# Scheduling a timeOut on mousemove

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mousemove

I'm reading [the events chapter in Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/14_event.html), and I have encountered the following code. Which is supposed to display the coordinates of the user's mouse every 250ms.

```
  function displayCoords(event) {
    document.body.textContent =
      "Mouse at " + event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
  }

  var scheduled = false, lastEvent;
  addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    lastEvent = event;
    if (!scheduled) {
      scheduled = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
        scheduled = false;
        displayCoords(lastEvent);
      }, 250);
    }
  });
```

I'm not understanding how the scheduling is working though. I understand that if you set a `timeOut` the handler will run after the set period of time, but I don't understand why in this example there exists a scheduled variable and a conditional statement to check its boolean value.

Without the variable and the if statement the program doesn't work as intended, it will print the coordinates without any kind of delay.
What is the logic behind this?

Comment: The logic is off. `scheduled` and the condition are useless, in this case, unless you have some other function that can set the `scheduled` var to `true` and stop the `setTimeout` `onmousemove`.

Comment: I thought they were useless too, but!

I was able to figure this out with Ori's help - see below

Since the timeOut is setting scheduled to false every 250ms, the conditional statement is a means of stopping the timeout from being called every 250ms.

Comment: Okay, my logic was off. Thanks for clearing that  up.

Comment: Yeah it's not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scheduled` flag purpose is to prevent the creation of a timer on each `mousemove` event call. Only after the current `setTimeout` is done, and the flag is false, a new `setTimeout` will be created.

Without the flag, the first call to `displayCoords` would come after 250ms, but subsquent calls to `displayCoords` will be fired one after the other, as each `mousemove` produced a timer, without waiting for the previous one to end.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense,

Comment: I think what was tripping me up, was the fact that I didn't understand that setting schedule to false in the timeOut only sets it to false every 250ms, 

I was thinking displayCoords was delayed by 250ms, but not the scheduled variable being set to false, so I was very confused as to how displayCoords was actually being delayed.

This is called a flag you said?
I was trying to google the pattern 'javascript schedule' and couldn't really find anything.

Comment: Exactly! The flag when true blocks any subsequent setTimeout, until the current timeout is done, and the flag is set to false. A Boolean variable that is used to save state for logic is called a `flag`.

Comment: Ok, it's a flag, I'll remember that. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I upvoted your comment, but I don't have enough rep for it to show.

Comment: Thanks, but you should accept the answer (and upvote if you like) - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I am so silly, I did not notice the huge checkmark next to your answer.